# How can I compare two data.frames and remove the same entries in the specific two columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to find the different rows in the same columns of two data.frames, how can I do that? For instance, I have two data.frames as a1 and a2, I want to compare a1 and a2 for columns ID and chr, and remove the same entires.  The expected output will be like a3.

````
a1 <- data.frame(ID = c(6,2,5,44,0), chr=c(1,8,11,21,12), loc= c(2,4,6,8,10), var=c(1,0,7,3,4))
>a1
ID chr loc var
1  6   1   2   1
2  2   8   4   0
3  5  11   6   7
4 44  21   8   3
5  0  12  10   4

a2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,44,45), chr=c(1,8,3,21,22), loc=c(2,5,6,9,13),var=c(0,2,3,4,1))
>a2
ID chr loc var
1  1   1   2   0
2  2   8   5   2
3  3   3   6   3
4 44  21   9   4
5 45  22  13   1
a3<-data.frame(ID=c(6,5,0), chr=c(1,11,12), loc=c(2,6,10), var=c(1,7,4))
a3 # expected output
> a3
ID chr loc var
1  6   1   2   1
2  5  11   6   7
3  0  12  10   4
# this part gives only the same rows and columns
library(data.table)
D1<- data.table(a1,  key="ID,chr")
D2<- data.table(a2,  key="ID,chr")
D1[D2, nomatch=0]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple one-line solution in `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::anti_join(a1,a2,by=c("ID","chr"))
```

---

Simple one-line solution in base R:

```
a1[!(a1$ID %in% a2$ID & a1$chr %in% a2$chr),]
```

**Output**

```
 ID chr loc var
1  6   1   2   1
2  5  11   6   7
3  0  12  10   4
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
#Create index
i1 <- which(a1$ID %in% a2$ID)
i2 <- which(a1$chr %in% a2$chr)
#Format
i3 <- intersect(i1,i2)
b1 <- a1[-i3,]

  ID chr loc var
1  6   1   2   1
3  5  11   6   7
5  0  12  10   4
```